# A superspace of an eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $a$ be an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$, then the eigenspace is given by $E_a=\{v\in V\mid(A-aI)v=0\}$.

Now define $F_a=\{v\in V\mid (A-aI)^tv=0$ for some integer $t\geq 1\}$. Clearly $F_a$ is a subspace of $V$ containing $E_a$, $E_a\subset F_a$, but I'm not sure if $F_a\subset E_a$?

I wish to show if $t$ is the smallest integer such that $(A-aI)^tv=0$, then $t=1$.

Answer (score 2):

try
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
5 & 1 \\
0 & 5
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Then
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
7 & 1 &0 \\
0 & 7 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 7
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks for the counter examples!